# Package a large data set

Tags: r, devtools

> Column-wise storage in the `inst/extdata` directory of a package, as [suggested by Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757793/946850), is now implemented in the [`dfunbind` package](https://github.com/krlmlr/dfunbind).

I'm using the [`data-raw` idiom](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) to make entire analyses from the raw data to the results reproducible. For this, datasets are first wrapped in R packages which can then be loaded with `library()`.

One of the datasets I'm using is largish, around 8 million observations with about 80 attributes. For my current analysis I only need a small fraction of the attributes, but I'd like to package the entire dataset anyway.

Now, if it is simply packaged as a data frame (e.g., with `devtools::use_data()`), it will be loaded in its entirety when first accessing it. What would be the best approach to package this kind of data so that I can lazy-load at the column level? (Only those columns which I'm actually accessing are loaded, the others happily stay on disk and don't occupy RAM.) Would the [`ff` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) help? Can anyone point me to a working example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, I would store the data in `inst/extdata`. Then create a couple of functions in your package that can read and return parts of that data. In your functions you can get the path to your data using: `system.file("extdata", "yourfile", package = "yourpackage")`. (As on the page you linked to).

The question then is in what format you store your data and how do you obtain selections from it without reading the data in memory. For that, there are a large number of options. To name some:

- **sqlite**: Store your data in a `sqlite` database. You can then perform queries on this data using the `rsqlite` package.
- **ff**: store your data in `ff` objects (e.g. save using the `save.ffdf` function from `ffbase`; use `load.ffdf` to load again). `ff` doesn't handle character fields well (they are always converted to factors). And in theory the files are not cross platform although as long as you stay on intel platforms you should be ok.
- **CSV**: store your data in a plain old csv file. You can then make selections from this file using the `LaF` package. The performance will probably be less than with `ff` but might be good enough.
- **RDS**: store each of your columns in a seperate RDS file (using `saveRDS`) and load them using `readRDS` the advantage is that you do not depend on any R-packages. This is fast. The disadvantage is that you cannot do row selections (but that does not seem to be the case).

If you only want to select columns, I would go with RDS.

### A rough example using RDS

The following code creates an example package containing the iris data set:

```
load_data <- function(dataset, columns) { 
  result <- vector("list", length(columns));
  for (i in seq_along(columns)) {
    col <- columns[i]
    fn <- system.file("extdata", dataset, paste0(col, ".RDS"), package = "lazydata")
    result[[i]] <- readRDS(fn)
  }
  names(result) <- columns
  as.data.frame(result)
}

store_data <- function(package, name, data) {
  dir <- file.path(package, "inst", "exdata", name)
  dir.create(dir, recursive = TRUE)
  for (col in names(data)) {
    saveRDS(data[[col]], file.path(dir, paste0(col, ".RDS")))
  }
}

packagename <- "lazyload"
package.skeleton(packagename, "load_data")
store_data(packagename, "iris", iris)
```

After building and installing the package (you'll need to fix the documentation, e.g. delete it) you can do:

```
library(lazyload)
data <- load_data("iris", "Sepal.Width")
```

To load the `Sepal.Width` column of the iris data set.

Of course this is a very simple implementation of `load_data`: no error handling, it assumes all column exist, it does not know which columns exist, it does not know which data sets exist.

Comment: Thanks, using `inst/extdata` didn't occur to me yet. You don't happen to have a reference implementation at hand? ;-)

Comment: I had a look at some packages that I thought that might, but I haven't been able to find a package which does this. I am trying to cobble together a rough example.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the way to go. I've been tinkering with saving the columns as individual data objects, but this has various issues. Currently in progress of packaging this: https://github.com/krlmlr/dfunbind